# Search is broken when appending data from tabletop to bootgrid

Tags: jquery

I load data form a published Google Spreadsheet using tabletop.

I then want to load the JSON output to bootgrid. Everything works fine, except for the fact that search is broken. Not sure if it's a bug or because I'm calling it just by "append".

```
var public_spreadsheet_url = "SPREADSHEETURL";

function init() {
    Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url,
                    callback: showInfo,
                    simpleSheet: true } );
}   

function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
    data = tabletop.sheets("Sheet2").all();

    for (var key in data[1]) { 
        $("#main-table thead tr").append('<th data-column-id="' + key + '">' + key + '</th>');
    }

    $("#main-table").bootgrid().bootgrid("append", data);        
}
```

Here's a fiddle, showing the problem much better: http://jsfiddle.net/ZM8LW/

BTW, I'm missing 2 tags because of reputation: jquery-tabletop, jquery-bootgrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did everything right but you forgot to reference the **jquery.bootgrid.css** file.

**UPDATE:**

The second thing was the missing `data-type` attribute (See the updated example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZM8LW/4/)).

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add it to the fiddle. However, the problem is actually in the search functionality - try to search for something presented on the table and see for yourself :)
EDIT: Here's the fiddle with the fixed style: http://jsfiddle.net/ZM8LW/1/